# What computational error am I making?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Okay, I'm reading over the textbook notes and I'm making up my own notes for the section. There is an example problem that I'm trying to solve out; however, I'm having some problem and  I'm not getting the same answer as them. I erased all the work and tried to do it again but I got the same answer. So, can someone check out my work?

$A = \{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$ where $a_1 = [2,1,1]$ and $a_2 = [1,2,1]$ and $a_3 = [1,1,2].$ $a_1,a_2,a_3$ are row matrices.

$$A=\left(\begin{matrix} 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 1& 1& 2\end{matrix}\right)$$

They want to find the characteristic polynomial of A and the eigenvalues.

$$\det[A-\lambda I] = 0$$

$A = \{a_1,a_2,a_3\}$ where $a_1 = [2-\lambda , 1, 1]$ and $a_2 = [1 , 2-\lambda, 1]$ and $a_3 = [1,1, 2-\lambda].$

I decided to expand by column one to get the characteristic polynomial: 
$$(2-\lambda)[(2-\lambda)^2 - 1] + [(2-\lambda) - 1] + [1- (2-\lambda)] = 0$$
This simplifies to:
$$6-11\lambda+6\lambda^2-\lambda^3 = 0$$

This is not correct. The book's characteristic polynomial is $-\lambda^3 + 6\lambda^2 - 9\lambda + 4 = 0$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The middle term should be negative.

Comment: The coefficients of the $2\times2$ determinants should alternate between 1 and -1. So you should have $(2-(\lambda))((2-(\lambda))^2 - 1) {\color{red}{-}} ((2-(\lambda)) - 1) + (1- (2-(\lambda))) = 0$. In other words, you've applied an incorrect formula for the column expansion.

Comment: Oh, I always forget  that! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you take the determinant of a matrix by column expansion, you need to alternate the signs.

$$\det\begin{pmatrix} a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\ a_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\ a_3 & b_3 & c_3 \end{pmatrix} = a_1 \det\begin{pmatrix} b_2 & c_2 \\ b_3 & c_3 \end{pmatrix} - b_1 \det\begin{pmatrix} a_2 & c_2 \\ b_3 & c_3 \end{pmatrix} + c_1 \det\begin{pmatrix} a_2 & b_2 \\ a_3 & b_3 \end{pmatrix}$$

When you computed your characteristic polynomial, you forgot the negative sign of the second term.